# Calculating x-value when moving a div

Tags: javascript, css

How to calculate the x-value of a div when it is moved horizontally.
I can see the property changing of that div like this- **transform: translate3d(-112px, 0px, 0px);**

I want to get the value of x that is -112px through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have something like this:

```
<div id="test" style="transform: translate3d(-112px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
```

The javascript code to get the x value is this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
// get the style value
var tranform = div.style.transform;
// transform will contain this: "translate3d(-112px, 0px, 0px)"
// Now use regexp to get the x value eg: tranform.match(/.{0,1}\d+px/) returns this Array [ "-112px" ]
// So the following code will return the value "-112px".
var x = tranform.match(/[-]*\d+px/)[0];
```

UPDATE: Regular expression explained

> /[-]{0,1}\d+px/

`[-]{0,1}` will match - sign if there is any
`\d+` will match any number
`px` will match "px" string

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the absolute screen position of an element is by using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```
var element = document.getElementById('id-of-the-moving-element');
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;
```

You can find some more details for `getBoundingClientRect` [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/).